# recovery partition does not seems to be exist

Tags: recovery-mode

Hi all I have successfully root my innos a35 phone and now what I want is to
There's no file called /proc/mtd , So is that mean that my device is not based on the
mtd technology.

I have tried the fastboot but it seems not working.

My /proc/mounts is look like this bellow.

```
cat /proc/mounts
rootfs / rootfs ro,relatime 0 0
tmpfs /dev tmpfs rw,relatime,mode=755 0 0
devpts /dev/pts devpts rw,relatime,mode=600 0 0
proc /proc proc rw,relatime 0 0
sysfs /sys sysfs rw,relatime 0 0
none /acct cgroup rw,relatime,cpuacct 0 0
debugfs /mnt/debugfs debugfs rw,relatime 0 0
tmpfs /mnt/asec tmpfs rw,relatime,mode=755,gid=1000 0 0
tmpfs /mnt/obb tmpfs rw,relatime,mode=755,gid=1000 0 0
none /dev/cpuctl cgroup rw,relatime,cpu 0 0
/dev/block/mmcblk0p12 /system ext4 ro,relatime,barrier=1,data=ordered 0 0
/dev/block/mmcblk0p13 /data ext4 rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,barrier=1,nodelalloc,d
ata=ordered,noauto_da_alloc,noinit_inode_table 0 0
/dev/block/mmcblk0p15 /cache ext4 rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,barrier=1,data=ordere
d 0 0
/dev/block/vold/179:33 /mnt/sdcard vfat rw,dirsync,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,
uid=1000,gid=1015,fmask=0602,dmask=0602,allow_utime=0020,codepage=cp437,iocharse
t=iso8859-1,shortname=mixed,utf8,errors=remount-ro 0 0
/dev/block/vold/179:33 /mnt/secure/asec vfat rw,dirsync,nosuid,nodev,noexec,rela
time,uid=1000,gid=1015,fmask=0602,dmask=0602,allow_utime=0020,codepage=cp437,ioc
harset=iso8859-1,shortname=mixed,utf8,errors=remount-ro 0 0
tmpfs /mnt/sdcard/.android_secure tmpfs ro,relatime,size=0k,mode=000 0 0
/dev/block/vold/179:18 /mnt/emmc vfat rw,dirsync,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,ui
d=1000,gid=1015,fmask=0602,dmask=0602,allow_utime=0020,codepage=cp437,iocharset=
iso8859-1,shortname=mixed,utf8,errors=remount-ro 0 0
#
```

So I understand that /dev/block/mmcblk0 is a one device and it should be refers to the
internal SD card. Is this assumption is right here?
So I navigate into /dev/block/ and executed 'ls' there.
I could find these files there.

```
mmcblk1p1
mmcblk1
mmcblk0p20
mmcblk0p19
mmcblk0p18
mmcblk0p17
mmcblk0p16
mmcblk0p15
mmcblk0p14
mmcblk0p13
mmcblk0p12
mmcblk0p11
mmcblk0p10
mmcblk0p9
mmcblk0p8
mmcblk0p7
mmcblk0p6
mmcblk0p5
mmcblk0p4
mmcblk0p3
mmcblk0p2
mmcblk0p1
platform
mmcblk0
```

What are those devices normally? So mmcblk0 does represent the whole partition table 
there right?

I want to know how it was partitioned ahead, what address mapped to where and what
partition mapped to where.

So from them what is the recovery partition?
What is the booting procedure of this device? I mean device first sector of mcblk0 into it's memory and then it does starts executing there. Am I right?
Or the startup rom [I have no clue what's going on] does configured to directly read the
partition titles and load the recovery images? What is going on here?

If I dumped those partitions as hex files , is there any signature or something that
I could used to assume which is what?

Comment: If the phone does not have `/proc/mtd` (IMHO should have, even with no real info), you should have `/proc/emmc`. Also try to examine file `/proc/dumchar_info` [Source](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15846294/how-to-read-a-specific-region-in-android-emmc)

Answer (score 1):

I was able to gather that required information through reading a log

```
Starting recovery on Sat Oct  5 16:12:57 2013
framebuffer: fd 4 (320 x 480)

recovery filesystem table
=========================   
0 /tmp ramdisk (null) (null)   
1 /boot emmc /dev/block/mmcblk0p8 (null)   
2 /cache ext4 /dev/block/mmcblk0p15 (null)   
3 /data ext4 /dev/block/mmcblk0p13 (null)   
4 /recovery emmc /dev/block/mmcblk0p16 (null)   
5 /misc emmc /dev/block/mmcblk0p19 (null)
6 /sdcard vfat /dev/block/mmcblk1p1 /dev/block/mmcblk1   
7 /system ext4 /dev/block/mmcblk0p12 (null)   
8 /sys_boot vfat /dev/block/mmcblk0p3 (null)

Command: "/sbin/recovery"
```

It's also known as the recovery log, don't know whether there's a connection. It shows all the partitions which are mounted. I used the 
`dd` command and flashed the recovery partition `/dev/block/mmcblk0p16` as listed here:

```
dd if=recovery_image of=/dev/block/mmcblk0p16
```

**NOTE:** This resulted me a broken recovery image. (I think they are still not supporting this device). Good thing that I have already backed up the recovery image.

```
dd if=/dev/block/mmcblk0p16 of=recovery_backup.img
```

So I have replaced it with the backup again and it's working back.